# Where can I find the default controls for Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

Can someone give a link to or explanation of the basic controls used in dota 2?

For example: push to talk key for microphone, team chat vs all chat, if there is a town portal hot key?

Comment: Your best bet is to look at the bindings and play some bot games practicing hotkeys. I good summary is possible I just don't think it's as practical as going out to try hotkeys yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access all of the controls and lots of other settings for DOTA 2, click the button that has a picture of a gear. This button is located in the top left hand corner of the screen.

You can also access and modify these settings while you are in game by clicking a button to go to the main DOTA 2 menu (located at the top left hand corner of the screen) which will then display the Gear button (screenshots included below).

If you want to test out some of the controls or try out new keybindings or some of the hotkeys I would suggest you start up a practice game against bots and then try reconfiguring / practising the new controls.

I think the default DOTA 2 keys are ok to start out with playing, but once you start getting into the game, you will definitely want to customize the keybindings. I think Decency gives a good starting point but please remember, that everyone's keybindings **DOES NOT HAVE TO BE THE SAME**. The keybindings you choose should work for *you* and not necessarily for anyone else.

If you have a specific question about how a specific control works or what exactly it does, ask a *new question*.

[image: Button to go to Main Menu from in game]
[image: Settings button, and Player Controls]

Answer (score 4):

The default controls really aren't all that good. I recommend setting up some of the number hotkeys for your items and whatever you're comfortable with for voice chat. Team chat is just enter, all chat is shift+enter. Town portal is an item; there are no "summoner spells" and so you have to buy one each time you'd like to use it (it's worth it).

I'm going to suggest a generic hotkey set that will let you do everything you need that's also pretty intuitive. It's a cross between what I use, the defaults, and what I'd like to use in the future.

Again, these are my RECOMMENDATION, not all of them are DEFAULT:

- ` : Voice chat (but push to talk isn't ideal)
- 1 : Select hero
- 2, 3, 4 : Top row of items
- Spacebar and/or Mouse Buttons and/or T, G : other items

---

- QWER : abilities
- Control+QWER : level up abilities
- Alt+QWER : auto-cast abilities

---

- A: Attack
- S: Stop
- D/F : "Extra" 2 abilities
- G : Tower Fortification
- H : Hold Position

---

- Z: Stats (Control+Z to level up)
- X: Buy Slot (TP)
- C: Courier
- V: Quickbuy
- B: Shop (Buy)

Obvious goal: everything laid out intelligently within easy reach of one hand. Feel free to take it from there and change things around as you'd like!