# Should I change the default keybindings?

Tags: dota-2

I've been playing Dota 2 for some time now (I've played about 100 hours total, according to Steam.) One thing that I still frequently struggle with is hitting the correct keys for the items I have in my inventory. I thought about changing the keybindings for my items to 123456 (as opposed to zxcvbn), but I have some doubts about whether or not it's better to do that or just stick with the defaults.

What do you think? Should I go for it? Do you know of any pro Dota players who have changed the default key bindings significantly (as opposed to just adding new shortcuts to the existing ones).

Comment: This feels very opinion-based and not very answerable. Consider revising your primary question to something that can be answered with facts.

Comment: @authenticgeek I think that keybindings are not necessarily opinion based, in cases where Pro players strongly advise a specific keybinding pattern (if the asker accepts pro gamers as experts). However for this particular game there is not a strongly recommended keybind change.

Comment: For example in GW2 the default keybind for skills (1-0) is terrible and virtually all tournament players have rebound it, so in some cases it actually is pretty objective.

Comment: A vast number of Dota2 professionals use custom keybindings, I'd honestly be surprised if there was a single player using default keybinds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controls list for noobs?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114648/controls-list-for-noobs)

Comment: I gave a pretty detailed recommendation that's intuitive, functional, and efficient in the above answer- take a look.

Comment: Don't forget that since you have been playing for about 100 hours and you change your keybindings now, you will frequently press the wrong button because your mind has been trained with those combinations.

Comment: I use alt + Q/W/E for the top row of the inventory and alt + A/S/D for the second row. I find this comes natural with using the abilities on Q/W/E/R and i don't have to keep moving my hand. Also using CTRL + Q/W/E/R for upgrading the abilities works flawlessly.

Comment: @authenticgeek Okay, fair enough. I'm not really sure whether this question in it's current form is salvageable though. I'll move this question to Reddit, and probably ask a similar question here that's a bit more fact-based. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Most DotA2 players use the standard key binding. However, this is in part because many of them are veterans from the WC3 days, when it was awkward to change the keybindings. Some pro players do use other keybindings, so it is certainly not unreasonable. For this particular game there is not an agreed-upon keybind that is better than the default.